# Is it possible to ssl certify my nodejs backend to be possible to make https request to it?

Tags: node.js, ssl, github, certificate, backend

I'm using a vuejs app deployed on GitHub pages, and I was using a nodejs backend in Aws EC2 which worked pretty well, but now pages wants me to use HTTPS requests, and I need to have a certificate. I tried with greenlock-express which didn't work,all requests gave some errors which I believe are because I am trying to certify a public IP address, and I need to certify a domain.

Then, my question is, how can I upload a backend for free (trial of a few days) and make it ssl certified to be able to receive and response https requests?

Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a free SSL certificate from letsencrypt.org, then pass it to `http.Server` like this:

```js
let app = express();

// ...

http.Server({
    cert: "...",
    key: "...",
    ca: "...",
}, app).listen(443);
```

Comment: Yes but letsencrypt only gives you cert a domain, and I want to certify a IP address.